# C# WPF WebBroswer Control: How to use JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am using WPF WebBrowser control and I want to acces some of the JavaScript functions but there is the problem.

I can use InvokeScript and execute browser.InvokeScript("alert", "Hello");q but how to get element by ID or by TAG and how to assign that element to javascript var?

Example:
Javascript:
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("embed");
elements[0].doSomething();

C#:
How?

I tryed everything but nothing worked. Can anyone help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a late answer, but if anyone else needs it:

The direct C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname.aspx

```
HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("embed");
foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
    {
        elem.InvokeMember("doSomething");
    }
```

The alternative: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0746166

Basically you should create a function in JS:

```
var myCustomFunc = function(tagName) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName); elements[0].doSomething();
}
```

And then call it from C# with

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("myCustomFunc ", new String[] { "embed" });
```

The variable "tagName" gets replaced with "embed"